# Does a JbossESB installation also include BPM?

Tags: jboss

Does JbossESB 4.12 include JBPM? I saw it has option of a BPM Processor. Do i need to install it seperately?
I am using **JbossESB 4.12** with **Jboss AS 6**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obviously clear to me now that JBOSS ESB installer and JBOSS Esb server contains JBPM 3.x with it. I should have seen the jbpm.esb directory inside deploy directory, my bad.